Using regular expression to only retrieve lists
I am trying to retrieve the lists in the text below.
import re

# Read the content from the file (here we assume the content is stored in a string for demonstration)
content = """
Variation 1:
Based on the provided examples and the input sequence, the next anticipated actions for the input sequence [['Start'], ['Pick', 'mixing_bowl_green']] could be:

1. Pick the sponge (since wiping actions typically require the sponge).
2. Wipe the mixing bowl.
3. Place the mixing bowl.
4. Place the sponge.
5. Pick the broom.
6. Sweep.
7. Place the broom.
8. End the sequence.

Here is the completed sequence:

[['Start'], ['Pick', 'mixing_bowl_green'], ['Pick', 'sponge_small'], ['Wipe mixing_bowl_green'], ['Place', 'mixing_bowl_green'], ['Place', 'sponge_small'], ['Pick', 'broom'], ['Sweep'], ['Place', 'broom'], ['End']]

Variation 2:
Based on the provided examples, the anticipated sequence of actions for the given input can be completed as follows:

Input = [['Start'], ['Pick', 'mixing_bowl_green']]

1. The next logical step is to pick the sponge, as it is required for the wiping actions.
2. Then, proceed to wipe the mixing bowl.
3. Place the mixing bowl back.
4. Pick the cutting board and wipe it.
5. Place the cutting board back.
6. Pick the plate and wipe it.
7. Place the plate back.
8. Place the sponge back.
9. Pick the broom and sweep.
10. Place the broom back.
11. End the sequence.

Here is the completed sequence:

[['Start'],
 ['Pick', 'mixing_bowl_green'],
 ['Pick', 'sponge_small'],
 ['Wipe mixing_bowl_green'],
 ['Place', 'mixing_bowl_green'],
 ['Pick', 'cutting_board_small'],
 ['Wipe cutting_board_small'],
 ['Place', 'cutting_board_small'],
 ['Pick', 'plate_dish'],
 ['Wipe plate_dish'],
 ['Place', 'plate_dish'],
 ['Place', 'sponge_small'],
 ['Pick', 'broom'],
 ['Sweep'],
 ['Place', 'broom'],
 ['End']]
"""

# Define the regular expression pattern
pattern = re.compile(r"\[\['Start'\].*?\['End'\]\]", re.DOTALL)

# Find all matches in the content
matches = pattern.findall(content)

# Print the matches
for match in matches:
    print("#####")
    print(match)
    print("#####")
    input()

However, the code returns me
#####
[['Start'], ['Pick', 'mixing_bowl_green']] could be:

1. Pick the sponge (since wiping actions typically require the sponge).
2. Wipe the mixing bowl.
3. Place the mixing bowl.
4. Place the sponge.
5. Pick the broom.
6. Sweep.
7. Place the broom.
8. End the sequence.

Here is the completed sequence:

[['Start'], ['Pick', 'mixing_bowl_green'], ['Pick', 'sponge_small'], ['Wipe mixing_bowl_green'], ['Place', 'mixing_bowl_green'], ['Place', 'sponge_small'], ['Pick', 'broom'], ['Sweep'], ['Place', 'broom'], ['End']]
#####

as the first match which is incorrect. How do I write the regular expression to only match lists? The text between the ['Start'] and ['End'] must resemble a list i.e. a comma followed by square brackets. The output should be
list1 = [['Start'], ['Pick', 'mixing_bowl_green'], ['Pick', 'sponge_small'], ['Wipe mixing_bowl_green'], ['Place', 'mixing_bowl_green'], ['Place', 'sponge_small'], ['Pick', 'broom'], ['Sweep'], ['Place', 'broom'], ['End']]
list2 = [['Start'],
 ['Pick', 'mixing_bowl_green'],
 ['Pick', 'sponge_small'],
 ['Wipe mixing_bowl_green'],
 ['Place', 'mixing_bowl_green'],
 ['Pick', 'cutting_board_small'],
 ['Wipe cutting_board_small'],
 ['Place', 'cutting_board_small'],
 ['Pick', 'plate_dish'],
 ['Wipe plate_dish'],
 ['Place', 'plate_dish'],
 ['Place', 'sponge_small'],
 ['Pick', 'broom'],
 ['Sweep'],
 ['Place', 'broom'],
 ['End']]


This isn't a good fit for the capabilities of regular expressions. It can't easily tell when the stuff between [['Start'] and ['End']] is proper list contents. The numbered lists could be inside a triple-quoted string, which would make it valid list elements.

I've checked the problem and apparently the .* pattern is taking more characters than it should. To solve this, a more specific pattern can be created with the format of the list, the challenge is to match the following items:

Item with tuple format separated by comma: ['Pick', 'sponge_small']
Item with simple string format: ['Sweep']
Item with string and space format: ['Wipe plate_dish']

For each type of item, the following pattern was found:
pattern_1 = re.compile(r"\['\w+', '\w+'\]", re.DOTALL)
pattern_2 = re.compile(r"\['\w+'\]", re.DOTALL)
pattern_3 = re.compile(r"\['\w+ \w*'\]", re.DOTALL)

You can put the logic together into a general pattern using optional elements:
pattern_4 = re.compile(r"\['\w+\s?\w*'(?:, '\w+')?\]", re.DOTALL)

The new syntax allows you to make a section optional without it appearing as a capture group.
The pattern that allows you to capture both lists can be created using an operator that helps to separate elements with either space or line break.
Here's the final code:
pattern = re.compile(r"\[\['Start'\](?:,\s{1,2}\['\w+\s?\w*'(?:, '\w+')?\])*,\s{1,2}\['End'\]\]", re.DOTALL)

matches = pattern.findall(content)

for match in matches:
    print(match)

